# How to update a subdocument in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a problem while using update in mongoose. I have one collection that looks like this:

```
{
    "client": "XXXXX",
    "counts": [
        {
            "bank": "XXXXX",
            "agency": "XXXXX",
            "count": "XXXXX",
            "value": "XXXXX",
        },

        {
            "bank": "XXXXX",
            "agency": "XXXXX",
            "count": "XXXXX",
            "value": "XXXXX",
        }
    ]
}
```

What I would like to do is to update the key "value" of a client's count matching by the bank and the agency.

I tried this:

```
model.find({
    "client": "XXXXX",
    "counts": {
      "$elemMatch": {
        "bank": "bank name",
        "count": "count number"
      }
    }
})
```

but nothing happens. Someone can help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for updating you should use `update` or `updateOne` or `findOneAndUpdate` functions, but you use `find()`, change it

```
const filter = { name: 'Jean-Luc Picard' };
const update = { age: 59 };

// `doc` is the document _before_ `update` was applied
let doc = await Character.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update);
```

check the [$elemMatch in update](https://mongoing.com/docs/reference/operator/update/positional.html) if you want update array